# What is the length of the base of this isosceles triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

Assume there is a line $g$ with length $|g|$ and fix an angle $\alpha\in (0,\pi/2)$. Below $g$, draw an isosceles triangle with the two similar angles being equal to $\alpha$. The apex of this triangle is the center point of a circle that has the length of the two equal sides of the isosceles triangle as radius.

Now, draw another node on the lowest point of the circle and use it to draw another triangle having the same angles as the previous one such that every vertex touches the circle. What is the value of $|h|$ expressed using $|g|$ and $\alpha$, where $h$ represents the base of the second triangle?

[image]

Comment: Draw a vertical radius in the circle, which will make some right triangles.  You can find some trig relations in them.

Comment: By symmetry, it looks like all corresponding angles are the same, so both triangles are similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$h = 2g \sin(\alpha)$$

For further details, you should first name the points on your figure.

Now look carefully at the triangle CDF. It is isoscele. Can you compute the angle at F? Then what is the value of the angle at D? Can you finally compute the angle at C?

Once done, you should be able to compute the ratio ${DF \over CF}$ as a function of $\alpha$. Now this ratio is equal to ${DF \over CA}$. This is connected to the ratio $h/g$ and the formula follows.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I would be very interested in the details. I named the points.

Comment: Got you! The angle of the triangle CDF at F is $\pi/2-\alpha$ and, since it is isosceles, the angle at D has the same value. This means the angle at C is $2\alpha$. I can find the relation for the radius r of the circle that is $(|g|/2)/r = \cos(\alpha)$. Then, I thought I can consider the triangle CDG, where G is the middle point of h and get the relation $(|h|/2)/r = \sin(2\alpha)$. Combining, I get $|h|=|g|\sin(2\alpha)/\cos(\alpha)$. Where did I mess up?

Comment: You didn't mess anything. Recall that $\sin(2\alpha) = 2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)$.